# setState function call not updating state, MERN stack

Tags: reactjs

I want to set states for the following states with the data taken from my database..although address is shown in the console,this setState function is not working..pls tell me what is wrong here?

```
   componentDidMount(){


  fetch('http://localhost:3000/reg/view/'+ this.props.match.params.id,{
method:"GET",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
},

})
 .then(function(response){ 
  return  response.json();


   })
  .then(function(data){
  console.log(data.address);

  this.setState({
    username:data.username,
    shopname:data.shopname,
    shopdesc:data.shopdesc,
    address:data.address,
    city:data.city,
    mobile:data.mobile,

  })

    })
   .catch(function() {
     console.log('error handling');
   window.alert("something is going wrong..!!")
 });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use arrow syntax for your `then` functions to keep the scope of `this` to `componentDidMount` so `setState` works

Read more [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881)

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/reg/view/'+ this.props.match.params.id,{
    method:"GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then(response => { 
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.address);
    this.setState({
      username:data.username,
      shopname:data.shopname,
      shopdesc:data.shopdesc,
      address:data.address,
      city:data.city,
      mobile:data.mobile
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error handling');
    window.alert("something is going wrong..!!")
  });
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. This pattern will work with any fetches you do. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the setState callback function, as recommended in the React [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Here the main part of their recommendation:

*... setState() **does not always immediately update the component**. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate **or a setState callback** (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.*

So, using arrow functions and the callback, your code should be like this:

```
 this.setState(() => ({
    username:data.username,
    shopname:data.shopname,
    shopdesc:data.shopdesc,
    address:data.address,
    city:data.city,
    mobile:data.mobile,

  }));
```